# How do I do this with apache rewrites? (alter url if it doesn't contain a 1 of 2 strings)

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter, mod-rewrite

I've installed a .htaccess file containing rewrite rules (as suggested by CodeIgniter) seen below.

How can I add to it so that any requests for urls that don't begin with `members/` or `admin/` get `public/` put at the beginning?

i.e. if someone requests contact/, it should actually go for `public/contact` and so on unless they request `members/something` or `admin/something`.

**.htaccess at present:**

```
RewriteBase /

# Removes access to the system folder by users.
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^_system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# prevent user access to the application folder
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^myapp.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 [L]

# This snippet re-routes everything through index.php, unless
# it's being sent to resources, or searching for robots.text
# Add any OR's in here if you need other directly accessable Files/folders 
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1
```

**.htaccess - edited** - this is how it looks now:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^_system.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^myapp.*
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /index.php?/$1 

RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|resources|robots\.txt)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1      

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/(members/|admin/|public/|index\.php) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

It's returning a 404 for all requests at the moment. I'm sure I've got something wrong but don't know what :)

File structure is:

site_root/.htaccess
site_root/index.php
site_root/myapp/

Answer (score 0):

You can prepend the regex with `!` to mean "must not match". So you can achieve what you want like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^(public|members|admin)/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /public/$1 [L]
```

Comment: You should also add `public` into your condition, otherwise you may end up with `/public/public/contact` etc

Comment: Thanks guys, I added 'public' to the must not match criteria. however I seem to be getting this error when I try mysite.com/contact/ now : http://cl.ly/20362j34023H3Z1Z1p2E

Comment: @gio 1) Where did you placed this new rule (update your question with new details) 2) Add `[L]` flag to the very last rewrite rule on your current .htaccess (I mean: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]`) 3) Where is your `index.php` is located? You may need to add it as exclusion to this rule as well (like you did with public).

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I'm adding a new answer because it is mostly unrelated to my old answer and is based on edits to your post. Leaving my old answer up for reference.*

There are a number of problems here, but there is one big issue which needs resolving before it even makes sense to address the small problems. It appears that you are using a framework that works by routing everything (with a few exceptions) through *index.php* (which surely has its own internal router to the application controllers in *myapp/*). But you also say you want to route everything (with exceptions) through *public/*.

These are mutually exclusive possibilities -- you can't route all traffic through two places simultaneously. So I can go into fixing the above rules and show the code, but only after I know what the rules are supposed to be doing. Given what you said you want in your intro text, combined with what is already in your .htaccess, it's impossible to figure out what the combined rules are even supposed to do. I can edit this post with code details only after you answer some questions:

- What framework are you using?
- What is *public/* supposed to be? Is it a directory (if so, what should it hold)? Or is something that is supposed to be routed to and handled by the application?
- Do your current *admin* and *members* sections work by going to *admin/* and *members/* subdirectories? Or are these routed to and handled by the application?
- Do you have any other important details about how the app is structured?